# segmantation fault while running depthimage to laserscan

Tags: nvidia, depthimage-to-laserscan

I'm using NVIDIA ORIN.The camera i use is Intelrealsense 435D .There is something strange happening here.When i pass message of topic camera_info and depth_image to package depthimage_to_laserscan and vizualise the /scan topic in rviz ,the terminal throws segmentation fault and terminates the code.Same code when i run it in my PC everything works fine.
Below line causes segmentation fault.

```
rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/t_depth_image camera_info:=/bef_camera_info
```

> Below code is on how i publish depth_image and camera_info

```
import cv2
import torch
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
import statistics as st
import math
import pyrealsense2 as rs 
import numpy as np
import threading
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from sensor_msgs.msg import CameraInfo
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
point1 = [0,0]
point_tl=[0,0]
point_tr=[0,0]
point_br=[0,0]
point_bl=[0,0]
p_bl=[0,0]
p_br=[0,0]
xA=0
xB=0
yA=0
yB=0
distance =0     
dis=0
theta=90
alpha1=62
alpha2=62
alpha_hori=75
a=480
b=640
x_s=0
h=0.11
x_real=0
z_real=0
width=0
depth_bl=0
depth_br=0
bounding_box = [0, 0,0,0]
mod = np.random.rand(480, 640) * 10
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5','custom', path='/home/htetro/ree_ws/src/test/src/best_wire1.pt', force_reload=True)
def dept_frame():
    frame_id = "depth_optical_frame"
def modify_depth_image(depth_image, bounding_box):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = bounding_box

        modified_depth_image = np.copy(depth_image)
        print(modified_depth_image.shape)

        modified_depth_image[:y1, :] = 100
        modified_depth_image[y2:, :] = 100
        modified_depth_image[:, :x1] = 100
        modified_depth_image[:, x2:] = 100
        return modified_depth_image
camera_info.header.frame_id="mod_depth_frame"
camera_info.width = 640  
camera_info.height = 480 
camera_info.distortion_model = 'plumb_bob'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Loading Intel Realsense Camera")
    pipeline = rs.pipeline()
    config = rs.config()   
    config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)
    config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 640, 480, rs.format.z16, 30)
    pipeline.start(config) 
    align_to = rs.stream.color
    align = rs.align(align_to)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
    pub_width = rospy.Publisher('/t_chatter_width', String, queue_size=10) 
    depth_image_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/t_depth_image', Image, queue_size=20)  
    camera_info_pub = rospy.Publisher('/bef_camera_info', CameraInfo, queue_size=20)
    bridge = CvBridge()
    camera_info = CameraInfo()
    rospy.init_node('light', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
# camera_info.K = [400.0, 0.0, 320.0, 0.0, 400.0, 240.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
# camera_info.P = [400.0, 0.0, 320.0, 0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 240.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]

camera_info.K = [381.243, 0.0, 321.739, 0.0, 381.243, 321.739, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
camera_info.P = [381.243, 0.0, 321.739, 0.0, 0.0, 381.243, 241.478, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]

while True:
        # Wait for a coherent pair of frames: depth and color
        frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        aligned_frames = align.process(frames)
        depth_frame = aligned_frames.get_depth_frame()
        color_frame = aligned_frames.get_color_frame()
        
       
        if not depth_frame or not color_frame:
            # # If there is no frame, probably camera not connected, return False
            # print("Error, impossible to get the frame, make sure that the Intel Realsense camera is correctly connected")
            # return False, None, None
            continue
        
    
        spatial = rs.spatial_filter()
        spatial.set_option(rs.option.holes_fill, 3)
        filtered_depth = spatial.process(depth_frame)

        hole_filling = rs.hole_filling_filter()
        filled_depth = hole_filling.process(filtered_depth)

        colorizer = rs.colorizer()
        depth_colormap = np.asanyarray(colorizer.colorize(filled_depth).get_data())
        depth_image = np.asanyarray(filled_depth.get_data())
        color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())
        color=color_image
        depth_fr=depth_image


        color_profile = color_frame.get_profile().as_video_stream_profile()
        color_intrinsics = color_profile.get_intrinsics()

        results = model(color)
        col=color
        # cv2.imshow("RGB", col)
        for box in results.xyxy[0]:     
                        xB = int(box[2])
                        xA = int(box[0])
                        yB = int(box[3])
                        yA = int(box[1])
                        point_bl[0]=int(xA)
                        point_bl[1]=int(yB)
                        point_tr[0]=int(xB)
                        point_tr[1]=int(yA)  
                        point_br[0]=int(xB)
                        point_br[1]=int(yB)                          
                        classs= int(box[5])
                        center_x= (xA+xB)/2
                        center_y=(yA+yB)/2
                        point1[0]=int(center_x)
                        point1[1]=int(center_y)
                        # Get depth value of the pixel
                        bounding_box[0]=xA
                        bounding_box[1]=yA
                        bounding_box[2]=xB
                        bounding_box[3]=yB
                         # Get depth value of the pixel
                        print("center x",int(center_x), " centeer y --->",center_y)
                        depth = depth_frame.get_distance(int(center_x),int(center_y))

                        try : 
                            depth_bl=depth_frame.get_distance(int(point_bl[0]),int(point_bl[1]))
                            depth_br=depth_frame.get_distance(int(point_br[0]),int(point_br[1]))
                        except : 
                            pass
                        p_bl = rs.rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(color_intrinsics, [int(point_bl[0]), int(point_bl[1])], depth_bl)
                        p_br = rs.rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(color_intrinsics, [int(point_br[0]), int(point_br[1])], depth_br)
                        # Deproject pixel to center point
                        point = rs.rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(color_intrinsics, [int(center_x), int(center_y)], depth)
                        width = abs(p_bl[0])+abs(p_br[0])
                        print("width of the object-------------------------->",width)
                        # Print the point coordinates

                        z_real=point[2]
                        if classs == 0 :
                                object = 'CARPET'
                        if classs == 1 :
                                object = 'GLASS'
                        if classs == 2 :
                                object = 'RAMP' 
                        if classs == 3 :
                                object = 'WIRES' 
                        mod=modify_depth_image(depth_fr,bounding_box)
                        print(f"The 3D coordinates of the point are: {z_real}")
                        cv2.putText(color, "{}m".format(point[2]), ( point1[0],  point1[1] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                        cv2.putText(color, "{}m".format(width), ( point1[0],  point1[1] - 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                        cv2.putText(color, object, ( point1[0]-50,  point1[1] - 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                        cv2.circle(color ,(xA,yA),4,(0,0,255)) 
                        cv2.circle(color ,(xB,yB),4,(0,0,255)) 
                        cv2.circle(color ,point_tr,4,(0,0,255)) 
                        cv2.circle(color ,point_bl,4,(0,0,255))
                        cv2.rectangle(color, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        
        cv2.imshow("YOLO color", color) 
        cv2.imshow("YOLO depth_fr", depth_image)
        cv2.imshow("MOdified depth", mod) 

        #adding frame to the modified depth image
        depth_image_message = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(mod, encoding="passthrough")
        depth_image_message.header.frame_id = "mod_depth_frame"
        depth_image_message.header.stamp=rospy.Time.now()
        camera_info.header.stamp = depth_image_message.header.stamp
        # camera_info.header.stamp=rospy.Time.now()
        hello_str = z_real % rospy.get_time()
        hello_str1 = width % rospy.get_time()
        rospy.loginfo(hello_str)
        pub.publish(str(hello_str))
        pub_width.publish(str(hello_str1))
        depth_image_publisher.publish(depth_image_message)
        camera_info_pub.publish(camera_info)
    

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```